# Excel Formula for match concatenate string with any value in cell > display this cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want a formula which will concatenate cell values plus several strings added by the user (i.e. I want to add a "/filepath/" and ".jpg") and check if that value is found in another column of cells.

i.e. check `if "/filepath/images" + CellA1 + " (rear view).jpg"`

I have this

`=INDIRECT("A"&(MATCH("*"&LEFT(H18,32)&"*",$A:$A,0)))`

but need to altered so that I can check a concatenate as opposed to a single cell value is found in row A.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use INDIRECT for this, you can concatenate by just using the & symbol.

```
="/filepath/images"&A1&" (rear view).jpg"
```

Comment: What about in a case where you want to check if a certain amount of words/letters match, it is not so much "match" as "contains" that I am looking for (in order to deal with anomalies).

Comment: You can check for substrings like this: `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("substring-you-want-to-search-for",A1))), [condition if substring found], [condition if substring not found])`. SEARCH is not case-sensitive, so it offers the most flexibility. If you need case-sensitivity then use FIND instead.